# Are array elements identifiers in java?

Tags: java, arrays, terminology, identifier

[Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/information/glossary.html) says that an identifier is "The name of an item in a program written in the Java(TM) programming language," but this doesn't specify if something of the form `myList[0]` counts as a name for the first element in myList. So, does `myList[0]` count as an identifier?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`myList[0]` is not an identifier. It is an [array access expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.3). The identifier in this case is `myList`.

Comment: Note: even though it's not an identifier, `arr[i]` is still a 'variable' per the JLS: "This *resulting variable*, which is a component of the array..", which could arguably lead to incorrect terminology if 'variable' is assumed to imply identifier.

Comment: @user2864740 Are you sure `arr[i]` is a variable? The [java glossary of terms](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/information/glossary.html) says that a variable is "An item of data named by an identifier," and `arr[i]` doesn't seem named by an identifier. I tried to find the definition in the Java Language Specification, but couldn't find if.

Comment: @Kyth'Py1k [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12)'s the definition of a variable in the JLS.

Comment: @Kyth'Py1k It is by definition, which is why I added a note - it surprised me when I first learned it was defined as such in Java! (In every other language I know I would say that it is not; but Java is Java.)

Answer (score 1):

No, myList is the identifier to the array, myList[0] refers to the element inside index 0 of that array, which a reference to a type of value.

Answer (score 1):

The ultimate place to check these definitions is the [JLS (Java Language Specification)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8) rather than a tutorial, which is naturally less formal.

According to said specification, an identifier does not include brackets. Therefore `myList[0]` is not an identifier.